# regex javascript, match from a certain position and skip lines containing comment block

Tags: javascript, regex

```
(1) // foo boo n(a){...}
(2)    foo boo n(b){...}
```

Is there a regex to match line 2 from

```
n(.){...}
```

, but skip lines that start with //.

Negative look behinds don't exist in javascript

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the text from the beggining of the line, validating it doesn't start with `//`.

**Regex**

```
/^(?!\s*[/][/]).* (n[(].*?})/m
```

- `^(?!\s*[/][/])` Uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) from the beggining of the line, to check it's not followed by spaces and `//`.
- `.*` consumes the necessary characters.
- `(n[(].*?})` captures `n( ... }` in group 1.

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sD3fR1/2)</kbd>

**Code**

```js
var regex = /^(?!\s*[\/][\/]).* (n[(].*?})/m; 
var text = '// foo boo n(a){...}\n    foo boo n(b){...}';
var m;
 
if ((m = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
    document.write(m[1]);
}
```

---

This will work for the examples provided. However, if you're trying to parse javascript code with nested braces, you won't be able to parse it with a regular expression.